# Ripping DVDs which (appear) to contain much more than 8.5GB

Tags: file-transfer, dvd

Recently I've come across an increasing number of DVDs which appear to contain far more data than physically possible. They appear to contain multiple copies of the main movie VOBs. Note that these are NOT Blu-Ray disks. They say "DVD" on the front and are being read in a DVD-only drive that does not support Blu-Ray.

For example, the Monsters University DVD has what looks like 11 copies of the actual movie. This generates problems with software like vobcopy on Debian, since it will try to read every file on the disk. I've looked around but been unable to find a clue as to how this is happening (does the ISO structure allow for hard links in the filesystem?), much less how to rip the actual content I care about and ignore the numerous extra copies. While I can by-hand scan individual VOBs from a disk, this is extremely tedious and if there's any way to do this automatically it would be great.

I've attached an 'ls -sh' on this particular DVD showing how the disk appears. Note the total size is (claimed) to be 81GB, not 8.5GB.

```
% ls -sh /mnt/dvd

total 81G
 34K VIDEO_TS.BUP
 34K VIDEO_TS.IFO
1.1M VIDEO_TS.VOB
 14K VTS_01_0.BUP
 14K VTS_01_0.IFO
 32K VTS_01_1.VOB
 12K VTS_02_0.BUP
 12K VTS_02_0.IFO
 32K VTS_02_1.VOB
 14K VTS_03_0.BUP
 14K VTS_03_0.IFO
412K VTS_03_1.VOB
 18K VTS_04_0.BUP
 18K VTS_04_0.IFO
1.7M VTS_04_0.VOB
 26M VTS_04_1.VOB
 14K VTS_05_0.BUP
 14K VTS_05_0.IFO
 11M VTS_05_1.VOB
 12K VTS_06_0.BUP
 12K VTS_06_0.IFO
 20M VTS_06_1.VOB
 16K VTS_07_0.BUP
 16K VTS_07_0.IFO
219M VTS_07_1.VOB
212K VTS_08_0.BUP
212K VTS_08_0.IFO
102M VTS_08_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_08_7.VOB
166M VTS_08_8.VOB
204K VTS_09_0.BUP
204K VTS_09_0.IFO
102M VTS_09_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_09_7.VOB
166M VTS_09_8.VOB
192K VTS_10_0.BUP
192K VTS_10_0.IFO
102M VTS_10_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_10_7.VOB
166M VTS_10_8.VOB
168K VTS_11_0.BUP
168K VTS_11_0.IFO
102M VTS_11_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_11_7.VOB
166M VTS_11_8.VOB
168K VTS_12_0.BUP
168K VTS_12_0.IFO
102M VTS_12_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_12_7.VOB
166M VTS_12_8.VOB
186K VTS_13_0.BUP
186K VTS_13_0.IFO
102M VTS_13_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_13_7.VOB
166M VTS_13_8.VOB
180K VTS_14_0.BUP
180K VTS_14_0.IFO
102M VTS_14_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_14_7.VOB
166M VTS_14_8.VOB
168K VTS_15_0.BUP
168K VTS_15_0.IFO
102M VTS_15_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_15_7.VOB
166M VTS_15_8.VOB
192K VTS_16_0.BUP
192K VTS_16_0.IFO
102M VTS_16_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_16_7.VOB
166M VTS_16_8.VOB
180K VTS_17_0.BUP
180K VTS_17_0.IFO
102M VTS_17_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_17_7.VOB
166M VTS_17_8.VOB
186K VTS_18_0.BUP
186K VTS_18_0.IFO
102M VTS_18_0.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_1.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_2.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_3.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_4.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_5.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_6.VOB
1.0G VTS_18_7.VOB
166M VTS_18_8.VOB
 16K VTS_19_0.BUP
 16K VTS_19_0.IFO
392M VTS_19_1.VOB
 12K VTS_20_0.BUP
 12K VTS_20_0.IFO
 32K VTS_20_1.VOB
```